# How do I make the output display an equation without an unexpected type error?

Tags: java

so i have to write a code that does regular divison and modolus division and have the output display the answer like:

```
14/4= 10
```

But when i try to write it, it displays an error.

Below is my code that i wrote:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Main  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int integerOne;
        int integerTwo;  
        int division;
        int modolus;
        int divisionTwo;
        int modolusTwo;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
        integerOne = input.nextInt();
        
        System.out.print("Enter another integer: ");
        integerTwo = input.nextInt();
        
        input.close();
        
        division = integerOne/integerTwo;
        modolus = integerOne % integerTwo;
        divisionTwo= integerTwo/integerOne;
        modolusTwo= integerTwo%integerOne;
        System.out.println(integerOne/integerTwo=+division);
        System.out.println(integerOne%integerTwo=+modolus);
        System.out.println(integerTwo/integerOne=+divisionTwo);
        System.out.println(integerTwo%integerOne=+modolusTwo);
    }

}
```

I tried to run it but i keep getting a "unexpected error on / and % symbols.

Comment: You can use `System.out.printf`. For example: `System.out.printf("%d / %d = %d", integerOne, integerTwo, division);` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that to print into the screen you need to format the message you want to print, and there are "rules" to do it. The way you are trying is not correct, you are actually executing mod and division instructions instead of printing a message.
You have multiples ways to format the output, but for what you've shown I think this is the easiest solution. Please try this:

```
String divOutput = String.format("%d/%d=%d", integerOne, integerTwo, division);
String modOutput = String.format("%d%%%d=%d", integerOne, integerTwo, modolus);
String div2Output = String.format("%d/%d=%d", integerTwo, integerOne, divisionTwo);
String mod2Output = String.format("%d%%%d=%d", integerTwo, integerOne, modolusTwo);
System.out.println(divOutput);
System.out.println(modOutput);
System.out.println(div2Output);
System.out.println(mod2Output);
```

So in detail what you are telling JVM is to format the strings according your input data, i.e., your integers. `%d` are placeholders for integers in Java formatting, have a look [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-string-format-method-with-examples/) for more details.

For instance `String.format("%d/%d=%d", integerOne, integerTwo, division);` for `integerOne=20`, `integertwo=2` and `division=10`, if you replace each `%d` by the given parameters in the given order, you will end up with `20/2=10`.

Note: `%%` will output only one `%`, it's the way we tell java to escape `%` in string format.

Answer (score 0):

you're mixing up the syntax for printing the result. In Java, you should concatenate the strings and variables properly for printing

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int integerOne;
    int integerTwo;
    int division;
    int modolus;
    int divisionTwo;
    int modolusTwo;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
    integerOne = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter another integer: ");
    integerTwo = input.nextInt();

    input.close();

    division = integerOne / integerTwo;
    modolus = integerOne % integerTwo;
    divisionTwo = integerTwo / integerOne;
    modolusTwo = integerTwo % integerOne;
    System.out.println(integerOne + "/" + integerTwo + "= " + division);
    System.out.println(integerOne + "%" + integerTwo + "= " + modolus);
    System.out.println(integerTwo + "/" + integerOne + "= " + divisionTwo);
    System.out.println(integerTwo + "%" + integerOne + "= " + modolusTwo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is happening when you try to compile your program, it's not a runtime error.

The actual error message that I get is:

```
error: unexpected type
        System.out.println(integerOne/integerTwo=+division);
                                     ^
  required: variable
  found:    value
```

That error is shown because you have tried to write an assignment statement:
`integerOne/integerTwo=+division` but the left hand side is an expression (producing a value) instead of a variable.